# Make grep succeed only if all patterns match

Tags: grep

I want to write a simple test that succeeds if all specified patterns are there in the output.

Specifically I am testing if my program is correctly using a configuration file to configure itself. This worked fine when I only had one parameter, but now I am doing the same with multiple parameters and it seems like I need to go the less quick and dirty way now because grep succeeds if any of the pattern matches, instead of all of them.

The program:

```
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "intParam is " << get_parameters().intParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "boolParam is " << get_parameters().boolParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "charParam is " << get_parameters().charParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "floatParam is " << get_parameters().floatParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "doubleParam is " << get_parameters().doubleParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "longParam is " << get_parameters().longParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "uintParam is " << get_parameters().uintParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "ulongParam is " << get_parameters().ulongParam << std::endl;
    logger_ << yaaf::LogLevel::info << "stringParam is " << get_parameters().stringParam << std::endl;
```

Current test:

```
 timeout 3 ${ini_test} | grep 'intParam is 1'

 timeout 3 ${ini_test} -i ${workspace}/tests/eclipseProject/algos/testsIni/initest.ini | grep 'intParam is 2'
```

What does not work:

```
timeout 3 ${ini_test} | grep -e 'intParam is 1' -e 'boolParam is false' -e 'charParam is a' [and so on...]
```

does not work because grep will exit with code 0 if **any** of the pattern match. I want it to return 0 iff **all** patterns can be matched against the output.

For this case I will probably just write some python code to do what I want, yet the case will probably present itself again in the future, or for someone else. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `grep ... | grep ... | grep ...`

Comment: @JamesBrown Ok that was way too obvious for me :-P  Thank you.

Comment: Please do check if this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762772/check-if-all-of-multiple-strings-or-regexes-exist-in-a-file

Comment: @Gautam looks good to me, feel free to flag as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762772/check-if-all-of-multiple-strings-or-regexes-exist-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep will get you the union (`OR`) of `-e` expressions.  You could solve this by chaining greps like `|grep … |grep … |grep …` but I see that your expressions are all plain text rather than regexes, so here's an awk solution that will be faster:

```
timeout 3 ${ini_test} | awk '
  function in(s) { return index($0, s) }
  in("intParam is 1") && in("boolParam is false") && in("charParam is a") {
    print
    retval = 1
  }
  END { if (retval != 1) exit 1 }
'
```

I've defined a function here to make it more legible (I assume you have a lot of tests given your "and so on" note).  It should be pretty obvious how to do this without the function.

AWK's `index(string, substring)` gives you the index of `substring` in a given `string` or else zero (awk strings are not zero-indexed), so if any of the requested substrings does not match, `index()` returns zero and the conditional short circuits.  AWK's `index()` is, in my experience, much faster than `grep -F`.

AWK always exits `0` (true) unless explicitly told to do otherwise in an `END` stanza.  You can add an extra `exit` at the end of the other stanza if that's sufficient to stop evaluations.